# Icon added after orientation changed..

Tags: android

In my app are 3 Tabs which are `Fragments`. In the first and second Tab are two menu icons on the `ActionBar` (icons are same). In the third `Fragment` which has a `ListView` is an search icon on the `ActionBar`. Every time when i am in the third `Fragment` and change the orientation of my device my app starts new and than the first Tab is selected. I know that this behavior is normal. But the problem is that the `ActionBar` gets the search icon from third Tab.

After i changed from first Tab to third Tab an back the icon disappears.

How can i solve this issue?

PS.: I use `SherlockFragments`..

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest file for the `Fragment` Activity.
You fragments will not get repainted.